# Excel - Copy and Paste a set range in the next empty row - not working when filtering

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have an Excel file with more than 2000 rows.
I often have to duplicate some cells of a given row and put it at the bottom, adding a new row of data, so I wrote this simple VBA code (linked to a hotkey) that copies the range from column I to column S of the active row to the first empty row at the bottom.

It works well, unless I run it when using AutoFilter.
I don't get any errors, it just doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

```
Sub copy1()

Sheets("DATABASE").Select

Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row & ":S" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy Sheets("DATABASE").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how robust this is but try the following:

```
Sub copy1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("DATABASE")

With ws

    Dim targetrange As Range

    If .AutoFilterMode Then
        Set targetrange = .Range("I" & .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count, 0).Row)    
    Else
       Set targetrange = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    .Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row & ":S" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy targetrange

End With

End Sub
```

References:

Vish Mishra  [header to next visible row beneath after vb-assisted filtering](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e31bd148-fd40-4b29-8ff3-e8ac093d7f1f/moving-programatically-from-header-to-next-visible-row-beneath-after-vbassisted-filtering?forum=exceldev)

Datsmart [TurnAutoFilterOn](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/258782-quick-vba-question-checking-if-filter-applied.html)

Comment: Hi and thank you very very much for your help. I've added your VBA to my file and it seems to work but it just copies to row #10, it doesn't add past that. Can I upload an example file so that you can see it? How?